# Cannot stop endless BSOD loop

Tags: bsod

I am getting the following endless loop when I try to start up my HP Probook laptop. I cannot get into anything or stop it even to try anything.

> A problem has been detected and windows has been shut down to prevent damage to your computer.
>
> If this is your first time you've seen this Stop error screen, restart your computer. If this screen appears again, follow these steps:
>
> Check for viruses on your computer. Remove any newly installed hard drives or hard drive controllers. Check your hard drive to make sure it is properly configured and terminated. Run CHKDSK /F to check for hard drive corruption, and then restart your computer.
>
> Technical information:
> ***STOP: 0X0000007B (0xFFFFF880009A9928,0xFFFFFFFFC000000D,0x0000000000000000,0X00000000000000000

I’ve tried to start in Safe Mode to no success. Tried Start Up Repair-no success. The Last Known Configuration option came up with a blank screen and just the mouse arrow.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: This looks like it may be helpful: [Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/blue-screen-with-error-code-0x0000007b/a2276974-ee92-463d-821a-bd7733c830ac?msgId=bf00b872-8d98-4c70-99c5-6e124ccf0193)  I just googled your error code to see.

Comment: Did you try the chkdsk /f suggestion from a command prompt outside of Windows and what was the result? I.e. did it successfully run and were there errors? Am I right in assuming this is Windows 7?

Comment: @kez It is windows 7. How do I run the check disk outside of windows?

Comment: During Startup Repair, which you mentioned you can get into, you can hit the cancel button to get to a menu (from memory at least).  At this point you can select the option to go into the Command Prompt and do the chkdsk from there.  Although chkdsk is "recommended" I would just be aware that it can sometimes result in data loss.  Make a backup of the data on your disk first, if you can.  Lots of posts on reading disks in other computers or cloning disks, etc, if you're not sure on this.

Answer (score 0):

[Do advanced troubleshooting](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324103) to understand what is going on and attempt to fix the problem; if it doesn't work you might be better of re-installing instead of wasting time on this unfortunate BSOD.

Comment: Ended up replacing the hardrive and a reinstall. Thanks eveyone for the help.